# SQLITE escape comment "--"

Tags: sql, sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I'm using DB Browser for SQLite, doing multiple inserts. However I need to escape `--` but it just keeps giving me errors.

`INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES ("S6--sfI6H6E"),("ASGts7sa6jw")` -- Error at S6

I have tried the following:

`INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES ("S6\-\-sfI6H6E"),("ASGts7sa6jw") ESCAPE '\'` - Error at ESCAPE

`INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES ("S6\-\-sfI6H6E"),("ASGts7sa6jw")` - Inserts Literal String

`INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES ("S6'-'-sfI6H6E"),("ASGts7sa6jw")` - Inserts Literal String

`INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES ("S6----sfI6H6E"),("ASGts7sa6jw")` - Error at S6

How can I escape `--`?

Comment: String constants should be enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=02458ed900d89feb3b43197bb4bdea08

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Perfect, thanks!